# Why is my "Advanced Armors" perk not working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As you can see in this first screenshot, I have the advanced armors perk.

[image: Advanced Armors]

And as you can see from this second screenshot, I can't craft neither scaled nor plate armor. What am I doing wrong?

[image: No Scaled or Plate Options]

As added notes in case it helps, I'm playing on PC and I added the advanced armors perk to my character through the console.

Comment: Look under the Steel section. Can you see Scaled and Plate there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scaled and Plate armor will show up under the existing category *Steel*, as they do not require their own materials.

Comment: Scaled and Plate armor only show under Steel for me. Are there versions for the other makes that I am missing or do they require alternate perks?

Comment: I thought I looked through all the categories, guess I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: @xantec I just didn't remember exactly where they showed up, so I wrote a vague answer. :P

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz They both come under steel, so I edited your answer.